# Objects in an array never call deinit? Why and How

Tags: swift2

I have object(element) in an array(elements) definded in Element class and ObjectSet class.

In my case, the objectSet object and element objects never call deinit function. please take a look "override func viewDidLoad()" function  in ViewController class. 

If I try to comment the line "objectSet.elements.append(element)"  the objectSet and element will call deinit function. Why?

Are they strong connected each other? and How do I solve this problem?

my code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let objectSet = ObjectSet()  //the objectSet is local variable
        for idx in 0..<10 {
            let element = Element(objectSet: objectSet, index: idx)
            objectSet.elements.append(element)     //try to comment this line  the objectSet and element will call deinit function
        }
    }
 }
class ObjectSet: NSObject {
    var elements = [Element]()
    deinit {
        print("ObjectSet deinit")
    }
}
class Element: NSObject {
    var objectSet: ObjectSet
    var index: Int
    init(objectSet: ObjectSet, index: Int) {
        self.objectSet = objectSet
        self.index = index
        super.init()
    }

    deinit {
        print("Element\(self.index) deinit")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're holding an `objectSet` reference (as a property) in each `Element`, so that's a retain cycle.

Try doing this:

```
class Element: NSObject {
    weak var objectSet: ObjectSet?
    var index: Int
    init(objectSet: ObjectSet, index: Int) {
        self.objectSet = objectSet
        self.index = index
        super.init()
    }

    deinit {
        print("Element\(self.index) deinit")
    }
}
```

More info can be seen in the Swift 2.1 programming language docs, specifically this ["Strong Reference Cycles Between Class Instances"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID51) chapter, especially the "weak references" section.